# How can automatic deploy yii2 app when Elastic Beanstalk instance is terminated and created a new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, yii2-advanced-app

Currently I have setup my yii2 website on AWS Elastic beanstalk. I followed following steps :

- Created Elastic Beanstalk app and environment : Platform PHP 7.0, RDS database
- Created SSH connection from EC2 instance of elastic beanstalk using putty with .pem file
- In Apache folder I have cloned my yii2 git repo using (sudo git clone repo_url) command
- Installed composer using this link https://gist.github.com/asugai/6694502
- Run command : (sudo composer install) in my repo folder
- Edited common/config/main-local.php and made db connection
- And run migration using (sudo php yii migrate)
- Setup a domain for this elastic beanstalk app

Now I don't know how should I proceed further and I am facing following problems :

- Elastic Balance loader is creating new instance and terminating current one when it fails or health goes in severe. 
  Due this, my all data in that instance is lost. To make it work I am doing all steps again and again manually.
- How can I make my domain https (SSL certified)
- How can make easy process to pull new changes from git

I already have a working site in nodeJS. which is using elastic beanstalk, elastic balance loader, RDS(postgres), S3 bucket, cloudfront for Route 53, SSL certificate (https), code pipeline, code commit. And AWSCLI at local to deploy nodeJS app.

my question is about I want to use same flow for yii2 advance app.

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance :)